# How does JSON.parse worked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
console.log(this.item_images)
console.log(JSON.parse("["+this.item_images+"]"))
```

I want to turn this.item_images into an array and loop over it, why can't I parse it? Below is the result in the console of above code. Note : I `console.log(typeof this.item_images)` it's a string.

[image]

Comment: Really? It looks like an array to me. Maybe the item at index 0 is a string.

Comment: Not an answer, but a solution: use `this.item_images.split(',')`. And please post more code, as both ways seem to work in a simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/zgtoj18k/ (maybe you have mixed single and double quotes?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.item_images` seems to be an array with only one element: the string '038...6aa'

So I guess you may want to *split* the string into another array.

```
var arr = this.item_images[0].split(',');
```

Then you can loop the array `arr`.

Update: If `this.item_images` is the string, use:

```
var arr = this.item_images.split(',');
```

instead.

Comment: this.item_images is a string.

Comment: @AliceXu No, just split the string into an array then you can loop it.

Comment: @AliceXu Then remove `[0]`. I saw it was surrounding by `[` and `]` in console, so I thought it is an array.